# API PLATFORM jwt access ignored

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

- I ask for a token, it works :

```
POST auth-user.coi.im/login_check   {"username": "reader", "password": "reader"}
{"token": 
 eyJ0eXAiOiJKV..........................................................." }
```

- without token :  **it's ok !  i have the error message**

```
    auth-user.coi.im/api/users/1
{"code":401,"message":"JWT Token not found"}
```

- with token :

```
auth-user.coi.im/api/users/1
Authorization Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV...........................................................
```

***Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to auth-user.coi.im/api/users/1.***

- or with curl and with token:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC......................"
```

***curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset***

HELP !
I have the same answer as if I put anything like url
why, does it work on my computer and not on a remote server?

Answer (score 1):

If you use apache server, it will strip any Authorization header not in a valid HTTP BASIC AUTH format

Create a **.htaccess** file at the root of your project, and add this rule,

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

Found in the : [jwt docs](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#important-note-for-apache-users)